# BASH script to handle "authentication realm"

Tags: authentication, svnsync

I have multiple SVN repositories which I intend to synchronize with other SVN server each night using **svnsync** like this:

> svnsync synchronize --source-username my_server_user_name --source-password ... --sync-username dest_server_user_name --sync-password ... svn://dest_svn_server/svn/[repository_name]

But it fails with "Authentication realm" error and asks to enter login-password - when I enter dest_server_user_name-password again - it succeeds.

Is there a way to do it automatically somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with bash?  (sounds like an SVN problem to me)

Comment: I think that automatic synchronization can be made using BASH script but if there are other ways to do it - it's perfect.

Comment: you are just looking for a set of commandline arguments to an SVN tool, you can write it in any shell or script or even in a C program...

Comment: I try to use such command options but server still keep requesting login-password.

Comment: I realize this question is a bit old, but let me ask two things: 1.) is the password empty? If so, try passing `' '` and 2.) does it contain characters that may require shell escaping? I ask because on tigris.org initially I had the same problem, but was able to overcome it with what I wrote in number 1.

Comment: Hm, really, password contains '$' and '%' signs but emracing them with apostrophes did not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to fix it:
1. Run **svnsync** with **--non-interactive** flag
2. Set property *store-plaintext-passwords* to *yes* within file ~/.subversion/servers